# how to make div container as wide as column

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a webpage I have developed, within this page I have used columns and placed images with a text and buttons overlay on them.

[image]

My problem is that this div with images placed in columns do not fit to the size of columns, Please look at this link: http://andymurphy.tv/index.php/landing/

This is what I am presently implement in each of this columns.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 406px;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.container:hover.image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container.image {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.container .middle {
  opacity: 3;
}

.text {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

```html
<div align="left">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tve_image_caption thrv_wrapper" style="margin: 0px -8px 0px 0px !important;"><span class="tve_image_frame"><img src="http://andymurphy.tv/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Image-a.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%" width="669" height="499"></span></div>
    <div class="middle">
      <div align="center"><span style="color : #fff;font-size : 26px">Watch</span><br><br><span style="color : #fff;FONT-WEIGHT : BOLD;font-size : 30px">THE STORY</span></div><br>
      <div align="center"> <button class="button1">Play</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please how can i get my div wif images to fill up columns size

Comment: if you want to do it so it's adaptive to the size of the screen, use bootstrap

Comment: u mean the div itself

Comment: yeah, so each div will be half the size of the column

Comment: u wana show me how to do this with the code i provided

Comment: im not sure i can without adding a fair bit of js code

Comment: I can't understand what are you asking. What is the desired result? I think you don't need bootstrap. However html code can be improved a lot.

Comment: wat i did there was pure css and html

Comment: @ marcos, presently my images dont feel the columsn they are placed in, so am trying to improve on that

Comment: Just a bit below in the same page you have those same two elements placed properly. What stops you to use the same structure and styles? `Start with the 
5 Day Masterclass` << those two are good, than again below you have another two that are misplaced...

Comment: they dont cover the left and right sides of columns respectively thanks

Comment: Since you are using a fixed height on your images - give the div a fixed height and set the image as a background image and then use CSS background cover attribute to make sure the image covers the whole div here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/6ejv9/

Comment: @anthony it still dosent fit column http://andymurphy.tv/index.php/landing/ iv replaced the image you used there in the example but ull see its nt fittin to the columns